# Почему в этом коде течет память?

Tags: c, утечка-памяти

Привет. Почему в этом коде течет память?

```
// Программа производит разность двух чисел с большим количеством знаков
// Условие: buf1 > buf2

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 500

int input_number(int buf_size, char *buf);
void output_number(int count_digits, char *buf);
char *reverse_number(int count_digits, char *buf);
char *diff_number(int count_digits, char *buf1, char *buf2);



int main() {
    char *buf1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
    char *buf2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
    char *res = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
    int count_digits;
    int count;

    count_digits = input_number(SIZE, buf1);
    printf("count = %i\n", count_digits);
    count = input_number(SIZE, buf2);
    printf("count = %i\n", count);

    output_number(count_digits, buf1);
    output_number(count, buf2);

    buf1 = reverse_number(count_digits, buf1);
    buf2 = reverse_number(count, buf2);
    res = diff_number(count_digits, buf1, buf2);
    res = reverse_number(count_digits, res);

    output_number(count_digits, res);

    free(buf1);
    free(buf2);
    free(res);

    return 0;
}


// разность двух чисел
char *diff_number(int count_digits, char *buf1, char *buf2) {
    char *res = malloc(sizeof(char) * count_digits);

    for (int i = 0; i < count_digits; i++) {
        // если условие выполняется, то мы занимаем из старшего разряда
        if (buf1[i] - buf2[i] < 0) {
            buf1[i + 1] -= 1;
            res[i] = (buf1[i] + 10) - buf2[i];
        }
        else
            res[i] = buf1[i] - buf2[i];
    }

    return res;
}


// Переворачиваем число, чтобы с первого разряда отнимать,
// а не с последнего
char *reverse_number(int count_digits, char *buf) {
    char *buf_reverse = malloc(sizeof(char) * count_digits);

    for (int i = 0, j = count_digits - 1; i < count_digits; i++, j--)
        buf_reverse[i] = buf[j];

    return buf_reverse;
}



void output_number(int count_digits, char *buf) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count_digits; i++)
        printf("%i", buf[i]);

    printf("\n");
}



int input_number(int buf_size, char *buf) {
    printf("Input big number: ");
    scanf("%499s", buf);
    int count_digits = 0;

    // Преобразуем в число
    // Элементы без цифры заполняются -48
    for (int i = 0; i < buf_size; i++)
        buf[i] = buf[i] - '0';

    // Считаем количество цифр в числе
    while (*buf++ != -48)
        count_digits++;

    return count_digits;
}
```

Comment: почему вы уверены, что в этом коде течет память?

Comment: valgrind пишет ошибки, могу прислать вывод

Comment: @DreamChild, пока не течёт, а просто не освобождается перед выходом. Но если функции из кода предполагается использовать неоднократно - потечёт по полной программе.

Answer (score 2):

`reverse_number` выделяет новый буфер и возвращает его. Старый - не освобождает (и не должен). то же самое с `diff_number`.

в `main` же вы выделяете буфер, запоминаете его адрес в buf1. А потом в строчке

```
buf1 = reverse_number(count_digits, buf1);
```

в `buf1` сохраняете адрес буфера, выделенного внутри `reverse_number`. Адрес же оригинального буфера, выделенного до этого строчкой

```
char *buf1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
```

вы просто теряете. И, соответственно, не вызываете для него `free`.

Что, в принципе, все равно не имеет значения, потому что ваша программа быстро завершается, и вся выделенная память все равно освобождается. Под утечками памяти обычно подразумевают накопление неосвобожденный буферов по мере работы, так что строго говоря у вас не утечка, а просто пару капель ошибки.

Если тяжело отследить по коду - попробуйте просто посчитать вызовы `malloc`/`free`. Каждому вызову `malloc` должен соответствовать вызов `free`, в который должно быть переданно именно то значение, которое до этого вернул `malloc` (именно значение, а не просто та же переменная).

Comment: То есть, чтобы это исправить, мне нужно запомнить первый указатель buf1, чтобы потом его мог освободить? Сделал так, создал char *tmp1, *tmp2 и присвоил им значения buf1, buf2, а потом free. Valgrind, говорит, что из 6 выделений памяти только 5 освобаждены.

Comment: @gnuvse. да. или убрать выделение буффера в `reverse_number` и `diff_number` - передавать им новый буффер параметром, например. память нужно освобождать на том же уровне, где она выделяется - так проще отследить проблемы.

Comment: Старая "шутка" про "I want to break free". Как раз про капли вместо течей. Не смог удержаться: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xUOTq.jpg

Comment: @PashaPash, я попробовал. И столько лишнего наплодил. Если я вас правильно понял. То я нагородил много подобного                                                                                    buf1 = reverse_number(count_digits, buf1, buf_reverse);
 free(buf_reverse);


 buf_reverse = malloc(sizeof(char) * count_digits);
 buf2 = reverse_number(count, buf2, buf_reverse);
 free(buf_reverse);

Comment: @gnuvse ну вот поэтому с C все перешли на C++ с (более-менее) нормальным управлением памятью. или вообще на C#.

Comment: @PashaPash, да ладно, прямо так и поэтому :) Просто C предполагает понимание происходящего на более глубоком уровне, чем C++. Никаких проблем с этим не вижу, но надо это или не надо - другой вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash, мне бы Си освоить, а ты про Си++, я ж там вообще утону.

Comment: @klopp, вот мне для понимания и надо. В общем сделал вот так https://github.com/gnuvse/c_git/blob/master/big_num.c

Answer (score 1):

Классическая потеря памяти, если выкинуть всё лишнее получается так:

```
ptr = malloc( 123 );
ptr = malloc( 456 ); // предыдущее значение ptr мы потеряли
free( ptr ); // и тут освободили только последний выделенный блок
```

Менее очевидный, но распространённый случай:

```
ptr = malloc( 123 );
ptr = realloc( ptr, 456 );
// если realloc() вернёт NULL, то память,на
// которую указывал ptr до её вызова, будет потеряна
```

Что тут можно сделать.

1) Вообще нет никакой необходимости выделять память под результат, если она выделяется в `diff_number()`:

```
char * res = malloc( SIZE ); // убрать, заменить на

char * res = diff_number(...);
```

2) В `reverse_number()` можно не выделять новую память, а реверсировать прямо входную строку.

3) Если пункт 2 не подходит, то или:

```
char *buf1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
char *rbuf1 = reverse_number( ...);
/* ... */
free( buf1 ); free( rbuf1 );
```

или:

```
char *reverse_number(int count_digits, const char *buf, char *result) {
/* и не выделять память, а записывать в уже подготовленный буфер result
    ...
*/
    return result; 
}
```